# Render Angular tags in injected HTML

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 15 application with a component, called FatherComponent, that receives via API a string of HTML that gets injected on its template using innerHTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlContent"></div>
```

My problem is that the received HTML content also has some Angular tags from another of my components, SonComponent, and they are not rendering.

```
htmlContent: string = 'Hi <app-son-component name="igorosabel"></app-son-component> !';
```

The SonComponent does nothing really fancy, just output that received name:

```
<strong>{{name}}</strong>
```

How can I force Angular to re-render the HTML to reflect the new received content? I have looked and tried several ways but FactoryResolver, Compiler... but they are already deprecated and I can't find an updated way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to sanitize the HTML or safePipe. https://blog.briebug.com/blog/how-do-i-display-html-inside-an-angular-binding

Comment: That is valid for regular html tags, but Angular tags such as <app-son-component> don't get compiled or rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do this because innerHTML doesn't look for angular custom tags to render.

Maybe you need to render component [dynamically](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), like in the following code:

```
export class DynamicContentComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentClass);
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();

    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<DynamicComponentRef>componentRef.instance).name = this.name;
  }
}
```

---

New way with ViewContainerRef.createComponent

```
import {ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

/**
your code logic
*/

constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef)

public addTable(): void {
   const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ComponentClass);

}
```

Comment: ComponentFactoryResolver is already deprecated, could you please change it using something else? thanks btw :)

Comment: you are right, now you can use [ViewContainerRef.createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent) without using the factory, i have updated the response

Comment: Ok, no errors or warnings now, thanks for the quick response. But... what do I do now? How do I use this to render or compile the tags that come in the HTML I'm injecting? Also, I suppose that instead of the ComponentClass of your example I have to put my SonComponent, no?

Comment: yes for the SonComponent instead, now you can add to your component instance input like name variable you need as `component.instance.name = "Iñigo Gorosabel"` and than in your SonComponent you can apply `<strong>{{name}}</strong>`

Comment: Oh! Ok, I get it now, using this technique I can create a component in runtime and then I inject it. But that's not the point of my original question. I'm getting via API a string of HTML like '<p>blabla</p><app-son-component name="User"></app-son-component>'. Using innerHTML I can inject it and the regular HTML tags are displayed, but I need to render those Angular component tags. And it is not just one <app-son-component> tag, it can be a lot of them. Thanks!

Comment: the problem there is that is not possible and a good practice transform complex string into HTML especially when string contains frontend custom tag. I suggest you to think again the solution avoiding complex wrapping like you did. Do this instead `<div [innerHTML]="'<strong>Name</strong>'"></div>`.

Comment: I simplified the components to explain myself, the components I am using are quite more complex and do a lot of things, not just say hello. Could I inject the HTML as I receive it, parse the string looking for occurrences of such components and then inject them on the appropiate place using your technique?

Comment: It worked! I parsed the HTML string searching for the places that needed the custom component to be injected, I looped them creating components as you showed me and I injected them in their respective places. And it worked :) You didn't give me the answer but you showed me the right way (this is the way!), thanks!